# Find the limit of the function $\lim_{ x\to 0^+}\arctan(x^{x^a})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{ x\to 0^+}\arctan(x^{x^a})$$ where $a$ is real number.
I have a problem because i don't know if i can get inside arctg with limit. So either this would help me or an explicit solution if possible.
New on this, sorry if I haven't written this correctly

Comment: Welcome to math.se. please use MathJax for formatting.

Comment: Please check that the edit is correct. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: it suffices to look at the limit of $x^{x^a}$, *since $\arctan$ is continuous.* Now, separate the 3 cases $a>0$, $a=0$ (easy one) and $a < 0$, after rewriting $x^{x^a} = e^{x^a \ln x}$.

Comment: @ClementC.Yeah, I needed to be sure about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Are you already familiar with the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x^x=1$ ? If so, then rise $x^{x^a}$ to the power *a*, and let $x^a=t$, then extract the *a*-th root of the result.

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in early comment, I needed to be sure of that fact. Thanks @Lucian